# how to survive a Fragment reference during TransitionManager Scene shift

Tags: android, android-transitions

I m trying the [Android TransitionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html) and it works good as long as I dont have a Fragment. Here´s a basic `Scene` setup where in the `setEnterAction()` after the Scene shift the `findViewById` is used to reattached the views.

```
       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_part2,
                    container, false);
            mContainer = (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.container);
            mTxManager = new TransitionManager();
            Transition transition = new ChangeBounds();
            mScene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mContainer, R.layout.grid1, getActivity());
            mScene1 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mContainer, R.layout.grid1, getActivity());
            mScene1.setEnterAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScene1.getSceneRoot().findViewById(R.id.item2).setOnClickListener(Part2.this);
                    mScene1.getSceneRoot().findViewById(R.id.item3).setOnClickListener(Part2.this);
                }
            });

}
```

The problem for me is I have a `Fragment` in `mScene1` and it gets lost. I´m not setting the `Fragment` in xml. How can I use only one Fragment between Scene shift without removing it and adding it again. It´s a complext Fragmnet so I must keep it alive?

What i was doing and not happy with is removing the `Fragment` when `mScene1` exit like this:

```
mScene1.setExitAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Fragment f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(HistoryFragment.class.getName());
        FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction1.remove(f);
        transaction1.commitNow();
    }
});
```

Then when `mScene1.setEnterAction()` runs I reattached the `Fragment`. I notice my app started lagging a bit because of the extra work of adding removing.

Is there a way to only have one Frag across `Scene´s`?